# how save a folder with some sub folders and files in mnt->sdcard?

Tags: android-sdcard, ddms

I want save a folder with some sub folders and files in `mnt->sdcard` on emulator from `DDMS`.I can save files one after other but I cant save many files at a time or cant save a folder totally in `sdcard`  because I am new by android.I did some searches but can not doing my job yet.what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
File root = new File(Environment
              .getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPrivateFolder");
if(!root.exists()){
        root.mkdir();
}
else{
    File[] files = root.listFiles(); //access your files
}
File myFile = new File(Environment
              .getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPrivateFolder/myFile.txt");
myFile.createNewFile();  // creating file
```

don ever hardcoe "/sdcard" or smth like this. for more convenient method of navigation each File has methods for accessing abosulutePath, getting info about is file or folder or even exists and other